# Returning polymorphic payload using RestSerializer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Say I have the following polymorphic relationships:

```
//animal.js
export default DS.Model.extend({});

//dog.js
import Animal from './animal';
export default Animal.extend({});

//cat.js
import Animal from './animal';
export default Animal.extend({});

//bird.js
import Animal from './animal';
export default Animal.extend({});
```

Now I want to fetch all the animals.

```
this.store.find('animal');
```

What should the JSON response be from the default RestSerializer given I want each polymorphic record to be transformed into its respective class?  Currently all my records are converted to animal instances instead of their correct type.

Answer (score 3):

When a relationship is polymorphic, the server response should indicate both the ID and the type of the returned object (the RESTSerializer does this by default); e.g.:

```
{
  "animals": [
      {
      // ... other attributes
      "type": "dog" // attribute that tells ember data what kind of Animal to instantiate
      },
      {
      // ... other attributes 
      "type": "cat" // attribute that tells ember data what kind of Animal to instantiate
      },
      {
      // ... other attributes
      "type": "bird" // attribute that tells ember data what kind of Animal to instantiate
      },
  ]
}
```

This means when the data is loaded, ember-data should instantiate the correct `Animal` object based on the “type” included in the data. (assuming the `Animal` model is declared with property `polymorphic: true`)

Here are some useful examples:

- [Example 1](http://www.codingepiphany.com/2014/08/18/simplistic-explanation-emberdata-polymorphism/)
- [Example 2](http://lukegalea.github.io/ember_data_polymorphic_presentation/#/1)

---

**EDIT**

You need to configure your Models to make them polymorphic. In your case, you could just add a parent object like `Zoo` that contains many `Animal` objects:

```
//zoo.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    animals: DS.hasMany('animal', { polymorphic: true });
});

//animal.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
   zoo: DS.belongsTo('zoo');
});

//dog.js
import Animal from './animal';
export default Animal.extend({
    // attributes ...
});

//cat.js
import Animal from './animal';
export default Animal.extend({
    // attributes ...
});

//bird.js
import Animal from './animal';
export default Animal.extend({
    // attributes ...
});
```

Now you can add a `Zoo` model to your JSON that contains ids of the polymorphic array of `Animal` objects:

```
"zoos": [{
        "id": 1,
        "animals": [123, 456, 789], // animal ids
    }],
"animals": [{
        "id": 123,
        "type": "dog" // attribute that tells ember data what kind of Animal to instantiate
        // ... other attributes
    },{
        "id": 456,
        "type": "cat" // attribute that tells ember data what kind of Animal to instantiate
        // ... other attributes 
    },{
        "id": 789,
        "type": "bird" // attribute that tells ember data what kind of Animal to instantiate
        // ... other attributes 
    }]
```

And you would request this JSON like `store.find('zoo', 1)`.

Here is useful app that will help you see how to structure your JSON responses based on your models. ---> [LINK](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/)

[Another useful example for ember-data polymorphism](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/750)

Comment: mmmm, that's interesting because that is the format I have been using and they are being resolved to Animal objects not their respective types.  Would the `type` property be camel cased (`"type" : "siameseCat`") or dasherized (`"type" : "siamese-cat"`)?  You said "assuming the Animal model is declared with property polymorphic: true", how do I declare a model as being polymorphic?  In my code above I have not declared anything as polymorphic.

Comment: @jas, type property should be camelcased to correspond to Ember naming conventions. For the rest, look at my edit.

Comment: damn, that is what I feared. This is an issue for me as I have some generic search components that accept a modelClass parameter.  It would be great if ember-data allowed you to explicitly force polymorphism `this.store.fetchPolymorphic('animal')` without the need for an intermediary.  Thanks for your help, I might open an issue in ember-data as I think this is impossible at the moment.